# How to open xml using XElement?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to load metadata.xml file from my machine, but it's gives error like

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

please let me help to find correct way for load xml using XElement.

**C# code**

```
private static void xmlProcess()
        {

            string filePath = @"D:\metadata.xml";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {

                // load xml file from destination folder
                XElement document = new XElement(filePath);

                var country = "IN";
                var curProduct = document.Elements("country").Where(t => t.Value == country).FirstOrDefault().Parent;

            }
        }
```

**XML File(metadata.xml)**

```
<root version="mech5.2">
  <language>en-US</language>
  <provider>Provider1</provider>
  <data>
    <title>Engine1</title>
    <vendor_id>ABC</vendor_id>
    <products>
      <product>
        <country>IN</country>
        <times>
          <time>
            <start_date>2017-01-15</start_date>
            <end_date>2017-09-15</end_date>
          </time>
        </times>
      </product>
    </products>
  </data>
</root>
```

why I'm getting this error: "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name"

Comment: The xml you posted is good.  Open the file with notepad and make sure it matches the one you posted.  I don't see a colon any place that would give the error you are posting.

Comment: I would change your query to the following : var curProduct = document.Descendants("product").Where(t => (string)t.Element("country") == country).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just [`XElement.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create and populate `XElement` from XML file :

```
XElement document = XElement.Load(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying using a wrong form of the constructor. `XElement` is trying to turn your filepath string into an instance name, and that's obviously not working. Try this.

```
XElement x = new XElement();
x.Load(filePath);
```

ps. double check the declaration of the constructor you're using
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292758(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for replay, This is  not XmlDocument. I'm using System.Xml.Linq.XElement.  Not working